# How to design Hash Functions for the problem of Set Intersection?

Tags: hash, data-compression

This is a specific question about [1].

Before the question, I must explain and organize some topics:

1) In section 3.2, during the "Pre-processing Stage", a hash function maps an element to a bit-string.

2) In the Appendix B, the authors explain the COMPRESSION stage of those bit strings.

Question:

Is it possible to design a specific hash function to make the Compression stage more efficient?

[1] Fast Set Intersection in Memory

http://arxiv.org/abs/1103.2409

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  More efficient than what -- more efficient than what's in the paper?  In that case, you're basically asking for someone to solve an open research question, which sounds a bit beyond what one can normally expect here.  Can you try to make the question self-contained, by telling us what properties the hash function would need to have to make the compression stage more efficient?

Comment: I started thinking: "It's almost the definition of noise to not be compressible", so a random (altough not trully random) binary hash function generated by a computer could not be the best choice for hashing. After that I started to search for hash functions in which the number of bits obey a Statistical Distribution to give me a Information-theoretic Bound for the Compression Rate. It is difficult to search a subject without a specific name and I was making no progress (I study this just for fun, it was not my objective to asking for someone to solve an open research question)

Comment: "what properties the hash function would need to have to make the compression stage more efficient?". This is my question too. I don't know.

Comment: OK, got it.  To turn this into a better question, I encourage you to spend some time working through the paper's scheme and try to figure out what properties the hash function would need to have -- that would make this more self-contained and give us more to work with, increasing the chance you get a useful answer.